# Postgres Streaming Replication Error: requested WAL segment has already been removed

Tags: postgresql, master-slave

I have setup streaming replication between a primary and secondary server. I have enabled archiving. In the Postgres log file I am seeing the below error.

```
< 2017-12-05 03:08:45.374 UTC > WARNING:  archive_mode enabled, yet archive_command is not set
< 2017-12-05 03:08:46.668 UTC > ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000000000000E3 has already been removed
< 2017-12-05 03:08:51.675 UTC > ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000000000000E3 has already been removed
< 2017-12-05 03:08:56.682 UTC > ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000000000000E3 has already been removed
```

Do we need to enable `archive_mode = on` for streaming replication? How can I avoid above error?

```
max_wal_senders = 3
wal_keep_segements = 32
```

Comment: I would start with increasing `wal_keep_segements` on master

Comment: I already set wal_keep_segments to 32

Comment: I would increase to be at least 1GB (~60 wals). and after you see the error above you jave to rebuild slave. Or enable archive_command instead of increasing `wal_keep_segments`, but again - in your situation, you anyway have to rebuild slave

Comment: Is it an ideal situation to rebuild slave every time this happens? What if even after increasing to 60 cause this issue?

Comment: please reread the link in my answer on how to plan and setup streaming replication. if you set up to 60 and it fails, then 60 is too low. set up to 2000 eg, or control transactions on master, or use any other approach described in link below

Answer (score 5):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html

> If you use streaming replication without file-based continuous
>   archiving, **the server might recycle old WAL segments before the
>   standby has received them. If this occurs, the standby will need to be
>   reinitialized from a new base backup**. You can **avoid this by setting
>   wal_keep_segments to a value large enough to ensure that WAL segments
>   are not recycled too early, or by configuring a replication slot for
>   the standby**. If you set up a WAL archive that's accessible from the
>   standby, these solutions are not required, since the standby can
>   always use the archive to catch up provided it retains enough
>   segments.

emphasis mine.

so either increase `wal_keep_segments` to big enough (enough for your amount of block changes), or configure `archive_command` and set up some storage to keep removed wals from master to be available for slave. Or configuring a replication slot for the standby...

Comment: You might want to add replication slots as a solution, and a more reliable one than wal_keep_segments.

Comment: I am using file based archiving. With recovery.conf file has the restore_command. But after sometime the WAL logs in the archive directory pile up causing out of space issues. Is the file based archiving is recommended or replication slots? If I do replication slots I don’t have to worry about archiving of WAL logs? Can I also use the archive_cleanup_command in recovery.conf file to cleanup old WAL logs?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe if I use replication slots I can avoid space issue, but are there any performance implications with this approach? Replication slots (log shipping) uses asynchronous replication. What about the data loss when a failure?

Comment: Using a WAL archive is a fine solution. You have to make sure that archives get deleted - use `pg_archivecleanup` for that. Replication slots carry no performance penalty. You use either a replication slot or a WAL archive - it is unneccesary to use both.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Continous archiving has a I/O impact on heavy load. Replication slots is better when you have lot of data being written.

Comment: If you need point in time recovery, you need WAL archives anyway. But choose the solution that fits you best.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to do reinit the replica in maintenance mode using below commands and it fixed the issue. This error was due to lag between leader and replica.

patronictl list

patronictl pause

patronictl reinit patroni

#### choose Replica pod

patronictl resume